# Formateadores en C

Tags: c

Hola estaba viendo en wikipedia los "Formateadores"  y me tope con este codigo, se supone que lo que pongo despues del % y antes de la d va a variar el resultado, pero en todos los casos me imprime el numero completo 1234.
para que sirven esos valores que pongo ? gracias..

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("%2d",   1234);  // for 34
    printf("%.2d",  1234);  // for 34
    printf("%-2d",  1234);  // for 12
    printf("%-.2d", 1234);  // for 12
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Pureba con números decimales, no con enteros :)

Answer (score 4):

**Caso 1:**

```
printf("%2d",   1234);
```

Ahí le estás diciendo que reserve un mínimo de 2 caracteres para imprimir un valor, en este caso un entero. Si quieres ver diferencias en este caso prueba a asignar un valor superior al número de dígitos:

```
printf("%10d",1234);
```

**Caso 2:**

```
printf("%.2d",  1234);
```

En este caso estás indicando que se han de imprimir un máximo de dos decimales... pero estás trabajando con un entero (que no tienen decimales). Lo que sucede aquí es que esa configuración se ignora.

**Caso 3:**

```
printf("%-2d",  1234);
```

Similar al caso 1. En este caso no solo el tamaño mínimo del campo es inferior al número de dígitos sino que además estás indicando que el valor se alinee a la izquierda... Para ver el efecto de esta configuración prueba a imprimir dos valores:

```
printf("%-10d%d",1111,2222);
```

**Caso 4:**

```
printf("%-.2d", 1234);
```

En este caso te pasa lo mismo que en el caso 2. El tipo `int` no tiene decimales, luego la configuración se ignora.

Comment: Hola gracias, me di cuenta que al agregar por ejemplo printf("%4d",  1234); no pasa nada, per si pongo  printf("%5d",  1234); que es un numero mas respecto 1234, lo que hace es dar un espacio en el lado izquierdo del numero.
a eso te refieres cuando dices  "Ahí le estás diciendo que reserve un mínimo de 5 caracteres para imprimir un valor", es solo para generar espacios amigo ?

Comment: @EmilyOrtega lo que estás haciendo es reservar espacio para imprimir una variable... Por defecto el carácter usado de relleno es el espacio, pero también puede utilizarse el 0: `printf("%08d",1234);` Al final no deja de ser un pequeño maquillaje a la hora de sacar valores

Comment: pero es necesario ese espacio para imprimir una variable ? porque qu pasasi yo imprimo sin las variables externas, me refiero solo asi printf("%d",1234) ahi el prgrama imprime normalmente, y sin esas variables externas igual se esta reservando espacio para imprimir una variable ? (en este caso reserva 4 espacios automaticamente)?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega Imaginate que estás imprimiendo una tabla de datos... Lo normal es que cada dato aparezca en una columna diferente... Y además resulta que hay datos que solo tienen 1 dígito y otros tienen 7 o más... Ese es un ejemplo donde se le saca partido a esto que estás viendo

Comment: gracias, una cosa, es posible poner otro caracter en ves del 0, ejemplo printf("%08d",1234);  poner unas comillas " ?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega no, no es posible. Para hacer eso tendrías que rellenar a mano los huecos (puedes usar un bucle para ello)